# ng serve --prod fails after upgrading to angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, ag-grid, angular8

After upgrading to angular 8, the ng serve --prod fails and gives the following error in the console.
Although ng-serve,ng build --prod works.

I tried npm cache clean after the update but no luck.

```
Uncaught TypeError: d is not a function
```

Here, is the package.json file for the reference. I am not sure how to debug this further.
Any help would be much appreciated. Am I missing something here?

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "compodoc": "npx compodoc -p src/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/http": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.14",
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.2",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.1.0",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.36",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^22.0.0",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.0.0",
    "ag-grid-enterprise": "^22.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.6.1",
    "devextreme": "^18.1.4",
    "devextreme-angular": "^18.1.4",
    "dhx-spreadsheet": "^3.1.4",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jszip": "^3.1.5",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^7.1.0",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^6.3.1",
    "ngx-push-notifications": "^6.0.0",
    "resize-observer-polyfill": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "^6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack": "^4.41.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@types/globalize": "0.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.5",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "codelyzer": "^4.5.0",
    "devextreme-intl": "^18.1.4",
    "igniteui-cli": "~4.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.3.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "protractor": "^5.4.2",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.6",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: try to remove the node_modules folder, and install again

Comment: Thanks, i tried the same..but no luck

Comment: refer this : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9929

Comment: I tried the solutions mentioned here..yet the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue on a few projects. I ran `npm i --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@latest` which seemed to fix everything for me.

Comment: Once remove all the node modules and install one by one node modules.After installing every node module enter ng build --prod it may help.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has the same problem.

I resolved it by making buildOptimizer to false in angular.json file

Comment: But by doing this, you'll loose all the build optimisation and tree shaking benefits. The issue is related to `angular-cli` version. Try downgrading or upgrading it globally.

Comment: Also, if some one comes across here, can refer : https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/3159